# How to calculate error and mean of values with uncertainty?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, standard-error, error

In an experiment in my phsics lecture I have to find out the value of the resistance of a resistor with the formular $V = RI$.

To do so I measured various values for $V$ and $I$ while $I$ changed $V$. I got the following table:

```
#   R [Ohm]   Abs. Error   Rel. Error
1   192,31    5,41         0,028
2   200       8,42         0,042
3   191,01    5,52         0,029
4   196,43    6,35         0,032
5   192,59    5,84         0,03
6   230       8,45         0,037
7   190,91    7,93         0,042
8   190       7,85         0,041
9   187,1     5,56         0,03
```

The absolute error I calculated with propagation of uncertainty. Now I would like to give a value for `R` with a confidence interval like $(R\pm\sigma)$ Ohm.

First I had to do it with linear regression. That was no problem and I got $(190,5 \pm 0,9)$ Ohm.

Now I have to do it by hand but I do not know how I should consider the error in my calculation. Is it possible to calculate the mean of $R$ and the mean of the absolute error? So simply $(1/9 \sum R_i \pm 1/9 \sum E_\text{abs} )$ Ohm.

Another idea I have is to calculate the standard deviation but then I would not respect the absolute error I have calculated already.

So how I can calculate a value for $R$ and the error of it?